# How do you combine multi level statistics into one table?

Tags: expss

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879269/how-do-you-remove-empty-rows-and-add-descriptive-columns).

**Reworded:**

Building on the previous dataset, `name` is now important for my summary statistics because there are multiples of some animals with different names. Instead, we can still carry a descriptive statistic in the `key_quality` field.

You will see that the resulting table contains all the individual statistics laid out nicely, but I would also like to see a mean of all baby dogs' heights for example. Then I would also like to see a mean of all baby mammals' heights as well. How do we add those stats?

```r
animals_3 <- data.table(
    family = rep(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 , 2, 2, 2, 2,3 ,3 ,3), 2),
    animal = rep(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), 2),
    name = rep(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6),2),
    key_quality = rep(c(rep("bold", 3), rep("smiles", 3), rep("sings", 3), rep("fast", 3), rep("sleepy", 3), rep("ticklish", 3)), 2),
    age = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 2),
    field = c(rep(1, 18), rep(2, 18)),
    value = c(
      c(25, 45, 75, 40, 65, 80, 10, 25, 50, 10, 15, 25, 18, 24, 40, 5, 15, 20),
      c(5, 15, 30, 7, 19, 40, 3, 9, 13, 2, 5, 9, 4, 7, 14, 1, 2, 3.5))
  )

animals_3 <- expss::apply_labels(
  animals_3,
  family = "|",
  family = c("mammal" = 1, "reptilia" = 2, "amphibia" = 3),
  animal = "|",
  animal = c("dog" = 1, "cat" = 2, "turtle" = 3, "frog" = 4),
  name = "|",
  name = c("fred" = 1, "billiy" = 2, "tod" = 3, "timmy" = 4, "ricardo" = 5, "jonno" = 6),
  key_quality = "|",
  age = "|",
  age = c("baby" = 1, "young" = 2, "mature" = 3),
  field = "|",
  field = c("height" = 1, "weight" = 2),
  value = "|"
)

expss::expss_output_viewer()

animals_3 %>% 
  expss::tab_rows(family %nest% animal %nest% name) %>% 
  # here we create separate column for name
  expss::tab_cols(total(label = "quality")) %>%
  expss::tab_cells(key_quality) %>%
  expss::tab_stat_fun(unique) %>%
  # end of creation
  expss::tab_cells(value) %>% 
  expss::tab_cols(age %nest%field) %>% 
  expss::tab_stat_sum(label = "") %>% 
  expss::tab_pivot(stat_position = "outside_column") %>% 
  expss::drop_empty_rows()
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry,  I don't quite understand the desirable layout of your table, especially in  combination with your previous question with 'name' column.

Comment: sorry "name" is no longer a descriptive-only column in this scenario. The layout of the table should have a group-level family stat of X and then a group-subgroup stat of Y and then a group-subgroup-member stat of Z. Does that make sense?

Comment: The crux of the issue is in the repeat of "mammal" for example. I would only want to see one line of "mammal" with its summary statistics and then directly underneath "dog" with its summary statistics and then directly underneath "fred" and "billy" before carrying on to see "cat" etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need different statistics for the same nested variables. For this case it is simpler to calculate all statistics for each group and then remove unnecessary rows and labels. It is very easy because resulting table is just a usual data.frame.

```
library(expss)
animals_3 <- data.table(
    family = rep(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 , 2, 2, 2, 2,3 ,3 ,3), 2),
    animal = rep(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), 2),
    name = rep(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6),2),
    key_quality = rep(c(rep("bold", 3), rep("smiles", 3), rep("sings", 3), rep("fast", 3), rep("sleepy", 3), rep("ticklish", 3)), 2),
    age = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 2),
    field = c(rep(1, 18), rep(2, 18)),
    value = c(
        c(25, 45, 75, 40, 65, 80, 10, 25, 50, 10, 15, 25, 18, 24, 40, 5, 15, 20),
        c(5, 15, 30, 7, 19, 40, 3, 9, 13, 2, 5, 9, 4, 7, 14, 1, 2, 3.5))
)

animals_3 <- expss::apply_labels(
    animals_3,
    family = "|",
    family = c("mammal" = 1, "reptilia" = 2, "amphibia" = 3),
    animal = "|",
    animal = c("dog" = 1, "cat" = 2, "turtle" = 3, "frog" = 4),
    name = "|",
    name = c("fred" = 1, "billiy" = 2, "tod" = 3, "timmy" = 4, "ricardo" = 5, "jonno" = 6),
    key_quality = "|",
    age = "|",
    age = c("baby" = 1, "young" = 2, "mature" = 3),
    field = "|",
    field = c("height" = 1, "weight" = 2),
    value = "|"
)

expss::expss_output_viewer()

animals_3 %>% 
    expss::tab_rows(family %nest% animal %nest% name) %>% 
    # here we create separate column for name
    expss::tab_cols(total(label = "quality")) %>%
    expss::tab_cells(key_quality) %>%
    # we name 'unique' as 'sum' to merge different statistics in one row
    expss::tab_stat_fun(sum = unique) %>%
    # end of creation
    expss::tab_rows(family %nest% list(total(), animal %nest% list(total(label = "|"), name))) %>% 
    expss::tab_cells(value) %>% 
    expss::tab_cols(age %nest%field) %>% 
    expss::tab_stat_fun(mean, sum) %>% 
    expss::tab_pivot(stat_position = "outside_column") %>% 
    expss::drop_empty_rows() %>% 
    where(

        (grepl("Total", row_labels) & grepl("mean", row_labels))  # to keep total and mean
        | (!grepl("Total", row_labels) & grepl("sum", row_labels)) # to drop mean with all other rows

    ) %>% 
    compute(row_labels = gsub("\\|(mean|sum|#Total)", "", row_labels)) %>% # remove labels 'sum', 'mean', '#Total'
    make_subheadings(1) # optional part

# |          |         |  quality |   baby |        |  young |        | mature |        |
# |          |         |          | height | weight | height | weight | height | weight |
# | -------- | ------- | -------- | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
# |   mammal |         |          |     25 |      5 |   45.0 |   14.3 |   68.3 |   27.7 |
# |      dog |         |          |     65 |     12 |  110.0 |   34.0 |  155.0 |   70.0 |
# |          |    fred |     bold |     25 |      5 |   45.0 |   15.0 |   75.0 |   30.0 |
# |          |  billiy |   smiles |     40 |      7 |   65.0 |   19.0 |   80.0 |   40.0 |
# |      cat |         |          |     10 |      3 |   25.0 |    9.0 |   50.0 |   13.0 |
# |          |     tod |    sings |     10 |      3 |   25.0 |    9.0 |   50.0 |   13.0 |
# | reptilia |         |          |     14 |      3 |   19.5 |    6.0 |   32.5 |   11.5 |
# |   turtle |         |          |     28 |      6 |   39.0 |   12.0 |   65.0 |   23.0 |
# |          |   timmy |     fast |     10 |      2 |   15.0 |    5.0 |   25.0 |    9.0 |
# |          | ricardo |   sleepy |     18 |      4 |   24.0 |    7.0 |   40.0 |   14.0 |
# | amphibia |         |          |      5 |      1 |   15.0 |    2.0 |   20.0 |    3.5 |
# |     frog |         |          |      5 |      1 |   15.0 |    2.0 |   20.0 |    3.5 |
# |          |   jonno | ticklish |      5 |      1 |   15.0 |    2.0 |   20.0 |    3.5 |
```